# How to Invoke function in user control from parent page asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-applications

Asp.Net 4.0

Is it possible to call a function in a user control from the parent page in code behind?
The user controls are created by other programmers, however each will have a common public function that i look for called "Output" which returns values in need for the main page. The main page has a main menu, so only one user control will display based upon the main menu selection.

Folder in WebApp with user controls:

```
> UserControls
  ProductA.ascx
  ProductB.ascx
  ProductC.ascx
  ProductD.ascx
  etc...
```

Code behind when user clicks a menu button:

```
Dim product As string = Session("MenuProduct")
Dim uc As UserControl
uc = LoadControl("~/UserControls/" & product & ".ascx")
InputPanel.Controls.Add(uc)
```

Function in user control I would like to access. This will be a common Function.

```
Public Function Output(ByVal ParamArray expr() As Object) As Object

   ...code

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call functions in a userControl from a parent page if they have the right access modifier. Public I believe

```
Dim product As string = Session("MenuProduct")
Dim uc As UserControl
uc = LoadControl("~/UserControls/" & product & ".ascx")
InputPanel.Controls.Add(uc)

if (uc is TypeWithMethod )
{
    Dim ucTyped As TypeWithMethod
    ucTyped = uc As TypeWithMethod
    ucTyped.Method()
}
```

Vb syntax is rusty, kept putting ; after every line.

Comment: It is already public. Because the uc is declared only as type UserControl it cant see it. Just wondering if possible some other way.

Comment: I see, you'll have to cast if first. Let me write some code snippet

Comment: That seems logical but .net is not recognizing TypeWithMethod in asp.net code behind when i type it in.

Comment: That's something you have to replace with the Type of your control. I assume you have have an interface they all extend from.

Comment: yes that is correct, there's like 40+ user controls and growing all the time. I could use a select case statement but i was hoping to have it done more dynmaically.

Comment: You just have to cast to the interface type. So if All of the 40 user controls extend iCoolControl then cast uc to iCoolControl and you'll be able to call your Output method. Assuming that Output is a method on the iCoolControl interface

Answer (score 0):

Here are little details to what andrew is talking about...

```
Public Interface IGroupable
    Function GetGroupId() As Int32
End Interface


Class MyUserControl
    Inherits UserControl
    Implements IGroupable
    Public Function GetGroupId() As Integer Implements IGroupable.GetGroupId
        Return 1
    End Function
End Class

Class MyPage
    Inherits Page
    Dim id As Int32 = DirectCast(myUserControl, IGroupable).GetGroupId()
End Class
```

So basicly create a Interface, have all of your user controls implement that interface, and then when you load any of your user controls within webpage...simply CAST them to the the type of your interface name....your interface will have the access to the function.